# MassTransit consumer partial failure retry strategy

Tags: c#, masstransit

Say I have the following consumer with a retry policy on it:

```cs
public class RetryOnlyFailedPartConsumer : IConsumer<Command>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Command> context)
    {
        await DoSomething();
        await DoSomethingElse(); 
    }

    private async Task DoSomething()
    {
        // Some discrete piece of work
    }

    private async Task DoSomethingElse()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

When an exception occurs I want to retry **only the failed part**, `DoSomethingElse()` in this case, and skip `DoSomething()` since it was successful to prevent it from executing multiple times. How can I do it?

Comment: The best practice is that one message triggers exactly one atomic operation, which either completes or fails as a whole, like a transaction. If those two operations execute against something that supports the `TransactionScope`, the transaction middleware can be used. If not, the best solution is to send two messages from this consumer and each of those messages will be consumed separately and do what they suppose to do.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev that's a good point. Both methods are actually designed to be a single atomic operation, however I cannot enclose them into the `TransactionScope`. Let's say `DoSomething` performs some calculations and publishes another message to the bus, how do I revert the message?

Comment: That's right, there's no way to repeat a single step. The consumer needs either to be split into two messages, or more advanced patterns like process manager (saga) or courier can be used, so you can do compensating actions. In general, if you are talking about one line executing the database operation and another one publishing an event, that's very hard to ensure consistency. Alternatively, you can ensure idempotency of the first operation one way or another, but there's nothing out of the box in MT to do it.

Comment: you could always catch the exception and retry it yourself. i mean, it's your consumer's logic, why go all the way back to MT for it.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I considered but hoped to avoid that. I've also discovered `GetRetryAttempt()` method on the context, maybe I can work around it somehow.